# robot_localization, odom topics frame_ids and tfs

Tags: navigation, ekf, odometry, ros-kinetic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use `ekf_localization_node` from `robot_localization` to create a `odom -> base_footprint` tf transform. For this I need other nodes (that capture raw odometry) to not publish this tf transform. But from these nodes I need various topics of types Odometry, Pose etc. And data in these topics must have a frame_id associated with them. The nodes providing these topics (gazebo right now, but plan to use turtlebot encoders, turtlebot gyroscope and visual odometry) set frame_id to odom there and apparently make some assumptions about the odom frame.

Is this a correct setup?

Do I need to set some other frame_id there?

What are best practices for this?

Won't these nodes mess up data when the odom transform is published by ekf_localization but not themselves?

Right now, my filtered odometry jumps around like crazy, while odometry from gazebo on which it is based is close to perfect.

### Update

This is my ekf.yaml for configuration. All topics seem to be  connected to where they should.

```
frequency: 30
sensor_timeout: 0.1
two_d_mode: false
transform_time_offset: 0.0
transform_timeout: 0.0
print_diagnostics: true
publish_tf: true
publish_acceleration: false

map_frame: map              # Defaults to "map" if unspecified
odom_frame: odom            # Defaults to "odom" if unspecified
base_link_frame: base_footprint  # Defaults to "base_link" if unspecified
world_frame: odom           # Defaults to the value of odom_frame if unspecified

odom0: /odom
# use vx, vy, vtheta
odom0_config: [false,  false,  false,
               false, false, false,
               true, true, false,
               false, false, true,
               false, false, false]
odom0_queue_size: 2
odom0_nodelay: false
odom0_differential: false
odom0_relative: false
odom0_pose_rejection_threshold: 5
odom0_twist_rejection_threshold: 1

#use vpitch, vroll, vyaw
imu0: mobile_base/sensors/imu_data
imu0_config: [false, false, false,
              false, false, false,
              false, false, false,
              true, true,  true,
              false,  false,  false]
imu0_nodelay: false
imu0_differential: false
imu0_relative: true
imu0_queue_size: 5
imu0_pose_rejection_threshold: 0.8                 # Note the difference in parameter names
imu0_twist_rejection_threshold: 0.8                #
imu0_linear_acceleration_rejection_threshold: 0.8  #

imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true



use_control: false
stamped_control: false
control_timeout: 0.2
control_config: [true, false, false, false, false, true]
acceleration_limits: [1.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.4]
deceleration_limits: [1.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.5]
acceleration_gains: [0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9]
deceleration_gains: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
# here go huge matrices, I did not change a thing from ekf_template.yaml
```

This is `/odom` topic from gazebo:

```
header: 
  seq: 54094
  stamp: 
    secs: 54
    nsecs: 245000000
  frame_id: "odom"
child_frame_id: "base_footprint"
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 0.638994661158
      y: -0.00382325493651
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.524965953165
      w: 0.851123227281
  covariance: [0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.05]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: -0.000107140599243
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.000144905498915
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
---
```

This is `/mobile_base/sensors/imu_data` (I'm not using most of it since real turtlebot contains only a gyroscope):

```
---
header: 
  seq: 994101
  stamp: 
    secs: 994
    nsecs: 252000000
  frame_id: "base_link"
orientation: 
  x: 0.000600978636132
  y: -0.00720100201285
  z: 0.0308421542399
  w: 0.99949814703
orientation_covariance: [1000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.05]
angular_velocity: 
  x: -0.000391028150828
  y: -0.00221559137064
  z: -0.0148769919816
angular_velocity_covariance: [1000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.05]
linear_acceleration: 
  x: 0.105053306153
  y: -0.0598538202618
  z: 9.90613778101
linear_acceleration_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
---
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283090/robot_localization,-odom-topics-frame_ids-and-tfs/) by [positron](https://answers.ros.org/users/33758/positron/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is this a correct setup?

Yes. Only one node may publish a given transform, so if you want the EKF to publish *odom*->*base_footprint*, then you need to make sure no other nodes are publishing that node.

> Do I need to set some other frame_id
> there?

No. If you have the `world_frame` set to *odom* for the EKF, it'll attempt to transform all future pose data into the *odom* frame before it uses the data. If it's already in the *odom* frame, you're golden. If, for example, you had some other world-fixed coordinate frame called *rotated_odom* that was rotated from the *odom* frame by a fixed yaw value, you'd use a `static_transform_publisher` to publish *rotated_odom*->*odom*, and the EKF would use that to transform the messages into the *odom* frame before using them.

> Won't these nodes mess up data when
> the odom transform is published by
> ekf_localization but not themselves?

No. Gazebo doesn't care what your state estimate is from some other package. It's just spitting out messages saying where it thinks your robot is. It's not using its own messages or transforms to do anything itself.

> Right now, my filtered odometry jumps
> around like crazy, while odometry from
> gazebo on which it is based is close
> to perfect.

I can't comment on this unless you provide your full launch file/configuration **and** a sample input message from every input into the EKF.

**EDIT 1 in response to updates**

You have the following issues:

- You have `two_d_mode` set to *false*, but you aren't measuring `Z` position or `Z` velocity.
- Furthermore, your covariances for roll and pitch velocity in your IMU message are astronomical - a value of `1000000.0` means you have a standard deviation of 1000 rad/s *for every measurement*. That effectively says to the filter "ignore this measurement; it can't be trusted."
- You don't have to do this, but as long as your IMU is providing roll and pitch, you might want to consider fusing them. Yaw is likely to be subject to magnetometer error, so you may want to leave that out. In any case, if you fuse roll and pitch from the IMU, fix their covariances too.
- Get rid of all `_rejection_threshold` parameters. Those are advanced parameters that should only be used once you have the rest of the filter working.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2018-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [positron](https://answers.ros.org/users/33758/positron/) on 2018-02-19**:
Thank you for clarification. Also, please take a look at configs.